# How to link Tkinter interface and API based program?

Tags: python, api, tkinter

I'm trying to link my Tkinter interface and a program I have to create with the Spoonacular API to get the recipe based with different parameters such as ingredient, diet type, and type of cuisine. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work.

The main objective is to link the Tkinter button relating to the diet type, intolerances, ... to the parameters (params) of my API program under. So the button will be affecting the parameters as are the variable asking the user to input information at the moment.

Here is the code for the Tkinter interface:

```
from tkinter import *
import requests

root = Tk()

def preferencesget():
    print(diet1.get(), diet2.get(), diet3.get(), diet4.get(), diet5.get(), diet6.get(), diet7.get(), diet8.get(), diet9.get(), diet10.get())
    print(intolerances1.get(), intolerances2.get(), intolerances3.get(), intolerances4.get(), intolerances5.get(), intolerances6.get(), intolerances7.get(), intolerances8.get(),intolerances9.get(), intolerances10.get(), intolerances11.get(), intolerances12.get())
    print(cuisinevalue.get())
    print(mealtypes1.get(), mealtypes2.get(), mealtypes3.get(), mealtypes4.get(), mealtypes5.get(), mealtypes6.get(),mealtypes7.get(), mealtypes8.get(), mealtypes9.get(), mealtypes10.get(), mealtypes11.get(), mealtypes12.get(), mealtypes13.get(), mealtypes14.get())
    print(ingredientsvalue.get())
    with open("preferences.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{diet1.get(), diet2.get(), diet3.get(), diet4.get(), diet5.get(), diet6.get(), diet7.get(), diet8.get(), }\n ")
        f.write(f"{intolerances1.get(), intolerances2.get(), intolerances3.get(), intolerances4.get(), intolerances5.get(), intolerances6.get(), intolerances7.get(), intolerances8.get(),intolerances9.get(), intolerances10.get(), intolerances11.get(), intolerances12.get()}\n ")
        f.write(f"{cuisinevalue.get()}\n ")
        f.write(f"{mealtypes1.get(), mealtypes2.get(), mealtypes3.get(), mealtypes4.get(), mealtypes5.get(), mealtypes6.get(),mealtypes7.get(), mealtypes8.get(), mealtypes9.get(), mealtypes10.get(), mealtypes11.get(), mealtypes12.get(), mealtypes13.get(), mealtypes14.get()}\n ")
        f.write(f"{ingredientsvalue.get()}\n ")


Label(root, text="The Muchies Generator", font="comicsansms 13 bold", pady=15).grid(row=0)


diet1= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Gluten-Free", variable=diet1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
diet2= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Ketogenic", variable=diet2).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
diet3= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Vegeterian", variable=diet3).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
diet4= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Lacto-Vegeterian", variable=diet4).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
diet5= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Ovo-Vegeterian", variable=diet5).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
diet6= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Vegan", variable=diet6).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
diet7= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Pesceterian", variable=diet7).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
diet8= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Paleo", variable=diet8).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
diet9= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Primal", variable=diet9).grid(row=5, sticky=W)
diet10= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Whole30", variable=diet10).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)


Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=6, column=0)
Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=6, column=1)
Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=6, column=2)


intolerances1= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Diary", variable=intolerances1).grid(row=7, sticky=W)
intolerances2= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Peanut", variable=intolerances2).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)
intolerances3= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Soy", variable=intolerances3).grid(row=7, column=2, sticky=W)
intolerances4= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Egg", variable=intolerances4).grid(row=8, sticky=W)
intolerances5= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Seafood", variable=intolerances5).grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W)
intolerances6= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Sulfite", variable=intolerances6).grid(row=8, column=2, sticky=W)
intolerances7= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Gluten", variable=intolerances7).grid(row=9,  sticky=W)
intolerances8= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Sesame", variable=intolerances8).grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=W)
intolerances9= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Tree Nut", variable=intolerances9).grid(row=9, column=2, sticky=W)
intolerances10= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Grain", variable=intolerances10).grid(row=10, sticky=W)
intolerances11= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Shellfish", variable=intolerances11).grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)
intolerances12= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Wheat", variable=intolerances12).grid(row=10, column=2, sticky=W)


Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=11, column=0)
Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=11, column=1)
Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=11, column=2)


cuisine= Label(root, text="Cuisine")
cuisine.grid(row=12, sticky=W)
cuisinevalue=StringVar()
cuisineentry=Entry(root, textvariable=cuisinevalue)
cuisineentry.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=W)


Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=13, column=0)
Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=13, column=1)
Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=13, column=2)


mealtypes1= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Main Course", variable=mealtypes1).grid(row=14, sticky=W)
mealtypes2= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Bread", variable=mealtypes2).grid(row=14, column=1, sticky=W)
mealtypes3= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Marinade", variable=mealtypes3).grid(row=14, column=2, sticky=W)
mealtypes4= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Side Dish", variable=mealtypes4).grid(row=15, sticky=W)
mealtypes5= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Breakfast", variable=mealtypes5).grid(row=15, column=1, sticky=W)
mealtypes6= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Fingerfood", variable=mealtypes6).grid(row=15, column=2, sticky=W)
mealtypes7= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Dessert", variable=mealtypes7).grid(row=16, sticky=W)
mealtypes8= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Soup", variable=mealtypes8).grid(row=16, column=1, sticky=W)
mealtypes9= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Snack", variable=mealtypes9).grid(row=16, column=2, sticky=W)
mealtypes10= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Appetizer", variable=mealtypes10).grid(row=17, column=1, sticky=W)
mealtypes11= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Beverage", variable=mealtypes11).grid(row=17, column=2, sticky=W)
mealtypes12= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Drink", variable=mealtypes12).grid(row=17, sticky=W)
mealtypes13= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Salad", variable=mealtypes13).grid(row=18, column=1, sticky=W)
mealtypes14= IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Sauce", variable=mealtypes14).grid(row=18, column=2, sticky=W)

Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=19, column=0)
Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=19, column=1)
Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=19, column=2)


ingredients= Label(root, text="Include Ingredients (seperate them by a comma(,)")
ingredients.grid(row=20, sticky=W)
ingredientsvalue=StringVar()
ingredientsentry=Entry(root, textvariable=ingredientsvalue)
ingredientsentry.grid(row=20, column=2, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="We assume you have: Salt, Sugar, Flour, Oil (the basics)").grid(row=21)

Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=22, column=0)
Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=22, column=1)
Label(root, text="-----------------").grid(row=22, column=2)




Button(root,text="Save Preferences", command=preferencesget).grid(row=23)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is my recipe program:

```
import requests

URL = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=3ff5df945cbb42ca9ee37873b5eaaae5"
user_query = input("What are you starving")
user_cuisine = input("What cuisine would you like?")
user_ingredients = input("What do you have in your fridge?")
user_diet = input("Choose from vegetarian, vegan, pescetarian or primal")


def getRecipe():
    params = {
        "query": user_query,
        "cuisine": user_cuisine,
        "ingredients": user_ingredients,
        "diet": user_diet,
        "instructionsRequired": True
    }

    response = requests.get(URL, params=params)
    print(response.text)


getRecipe()
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: are we meant to guess how you want them linked ?

Comment: Just did, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: How are these two files related?

Comment: create a variable for the params which are changed by the checkboxes and buttons?

Comment: It is my main concern, I am trying to link these two files. They are related in the way that this API helps you to sort recipes taking in consideration some parameters (params). My tkinter has some button that refers to the parameters key and values and i would like to make them affect my getRecipe() function ...